# weakly convergent and the inner product in $l^{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, weak-convergence

A sequence $\mathbf{x}^{(n)}$ in $l^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{N})$ converges weakly to $\mathbf{x}$ if, and only if, the sequence of inner products $(\mathbf{x}^{(n)} - \mathbf{x}, a)$ converges to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, for every $\mathbf{a}\in l^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{N})$

I didn't understand the weakly convergence, so I don't know how to start the proof of this. Anyone can help me to prove?

Answer (score 0):

In infinite dimensional real or complex vector spaces, sequences and topology in general don't behave as nicely as in finite dimensional ones. For example, the closed unit ball $\overline{B_1(0)}$ is not compact. Now while in Banach spaces you can (and will) always define a convergence based on the norm, and that convergence is defined in the same way as the convergence in, say, $\mathbb{R}^n$. But in general you don't have "enough" of those norm-convergent sequences, so you define the weak convergence. That is roughly speaking why this even exists.

Now to your question: there are several ways to define weak convergence. In most books I know it looks something like this:

Let $X$ be a normed space. Then $(x_k)_k \subset X$ is said to converge weakly to $x \in X$ if for all $x' \in X'$: $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \langle x', x_k \rangle = \langle x', x \rangle $$

and this is a limit in the real or complex numbers. Using that, you can relatively easy get to what you have to show (in the special case $X=l^2(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R})$ which is also a Hilbert space). You just need to think how elements in the dual space of a Hilbert space can be represented, and there is a very important theorem for that.